# How to get angle value in vtkAngleWidget class?

Tags: c#, c++, vtk, qvtkwidget

I am using Visual Studio C# and i want to get angle with using vtkAngleWidget.

[VTK Angle Widget Sample - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVC2b.png)

```
public void addAngleWidget() { 
        angleWidget = new vtkAngleWidget(); 
        angleWidget.SetInteractor(this.iren); 
        angleWidget.CreateDefaultRepresentation(); 
        angleWidget.On(); 
    }
```

With this code, vtkAngleWidget is working perfectly. But i want to write to angle, inside a textbox. Like this;

[Like this... - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEXHy.png)

How do i ? Thx for advices..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

`render3DWindow.angleWidget.GetAngleRepresentation().GetAngle();`

render3DWindow - My VTK Render Class

angleWidget - vtkAngleWidget